# Parse.com: saveInBackgroundWithBlock - block not called

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using the newest version of the Parse iOS SKD (v1.4.2) and getting my app actually ready for iOS 8...

Now I came across the following problem:

If a user subscribes to a push channel I am using the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` method to show an alert after the subscription was successful.
The problem is now that the succeeded block is never been called!

The subscription it self woking without any problem - the new channel is showing up immediately at the Parse.com backend.

So I am really confused! ;)

Does anyone have the same problem and especially have a solution for it?

```
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:channel forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            // Show success Alert
            UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [successAlert show];

        } else {

            // Show error Alert
            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlert show];

        }
    }];
```

**Update:** I played around with it and have noticed that the block is called but my alert is not shown...

Comment: What exactly are you doing the "Show success Alert" ? section?  If you are performing any UI tasks (such as a UIAlertView) then make sure you dispatch it on the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 I played around with it and I think you are right - if I use `NSLog` it is been called... But a UIAlertView not showing up :/ Can you help me to dispatch it on the main queue? 

`UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Succeeded" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [successAlert show];`

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushSucces) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];` - but the alert is still not displayed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the `succeeded` param. As with Apple APIs it's just a bit more save. This is how I would do it. Also since you are targeting iOS8 I strongly suggest using the new `UIAlertController` API.

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:channel forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]); // DEBUG

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertController* alert;

        if (succeeded && !error) {
            // Success Alert
            alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                        message:nil
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        } else {
            // Error Alert
            alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:nil
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        }

        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                  [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                              }];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

Comment: If I also support iOS 7 I need a fallback for the alert - right?

Comment: Right, `UIAlertController` is not back ported.

Comment: I used successfully [this library](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/RMUniversalAlert)